# How do you push data to a readable stream from within a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to achieve the following:

- Function `getPaths` reads directory paths and pushes them into `readable` stream as it finds them
- The `readable` stream keeps piping (streaming) incoming paths into the `write` stream as it receives the paths.

### Code

```
const fs = require('fs')
const zlib = require('zlib')
const zip = zlib.createGzip()
const Stream = require('stream')


let wstream = fs.createWriteStream('C:/test/file.txt.gz') 
let readable = new Stream.Readable({
  objectMode: true,
  read(item) {
    this.push(item)
  }
})

readable.pipe(zip).pipe(wstream)
.on('finish', (err) => {
  console.log('done');
})

let walkdir = require('walkdir')
function getPaths(dir) {
  let walker = walkdir.sync(dir, {"max_depth": 0, "track_inodes": true}, (path, stat) => {
    readable.push(path)
    console.log('pushing a path to readable')
  }) 
}
getPaths("C:/")
console.log('getPaths() ran')
readable.push(null)  // indicates the end of the stream
```

### Problem

The paths are not being compressed and written to the file as the `getPaths` function finds them and pushes them into the stream, it doesn't happen until it has found all of them. I know it's probably due to the process being synchronous but cannot figure out how to make it work.

I see the following output from the logs:

```
> // .gz file gets created with size of 0
> // Nothing happens for about 1 minute
> x(184206803) "pushing a path to readable"
> "getPaths() ran"
> // I see the data started being written into the file
> "Done"
```

### UPDATE:

And if I do this asynchronously like this (or use the code from the answer below):

```
let walker = walkdir(dir, {"max_depth": 0, "track_inodes": true})
  walker.on('path', (path, stat) => {
    readable.push(path)
  }) 
  walker.on('end', (path, stat) => {
    readable.push(null)
  }) 

  ...

  // readable.push(null)
```

I get an error (I think, it throws that particular error when it doesn't receive expected data chunk after you're done pushing data into it. If you remove that last line from the code: `readable.push(null)`, and try to run the code again it throws the same error):

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be one of type
 string or Buffer. Received type number
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `walkdir` but I imagine if there was an `async` function there, it might do the trick

Comment: @Amit I actually tried that, but then `readable` throws an error saying that it received a `number` instead of buffer. I think it throws this error when it doesn't see a `null` being pushed into it after you're done writing. I'm gonna edit the question now and add this info in

Comment: I suggest you log what you push (before you push), and see what happens (or better yet, debug that)

Comment: @Amit the thing is, it sends out the paths to `readable`, but they get stuck in there until the function ran. Because I can clearly see the file being written to disk after about 1 minute (after it's done reading all the paths and pushing them to `readable`)

Comment: @Amit I edited the question and added a log of what is happening during the process

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very good and works fine. You just need to remove `this.push(item)` and set `read` function with empty body.

Here is a working snippet

```
const fs = require('fs')
const zlib = require('zlib')
const zip = zlib.createGzip()
const Stream = require('stream')


let wstream = fs.createWriteStream('C:/test/file.txt.gz') 
let readable = new Stream.Readable({
  objectMode: true,
  read() { }
})

readable.pipe(zip).pipe(wstream)
.on('finish', (err) => {
  console.log('done');
})

let walkdir = require('walkdir')
function getPaths(dir) {
  let walker = walkdir(dir, {"max_depth": 0, "track_inodes": true})
  walker.on('path', (path, stat) => {
    readable.push(path)
  }) 
  walker.on('end', (path, stat) => {
    readable.push(null)
  }) 
}
getPaths("C:/")
console.log('getPaths() ran')
```

BTW, the right argument name is `read(size)`. It represents the number of [bytes to read](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size_1)

**EDIT**
There is no need for the readable stream. You can write directly to zip.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const zlib = require('zlib');
const zip = zlib.createGzip();
const wstream = fs.createWriteStream('C:/test/file.txt.gz');

zip.pipe(wstream)
.on('finish', (err) => {
  console.log('done');
})

let walkdir = require('walkdir')
function getPaths(dir) {
  let walker = walkdir(dir, {"max_depth": 0, "track_inodes": true})
  walker.on('path', (path, stat) => {
    zip.write(path);
  })
  walker.on('end', (path, stat) => {
    zip.end();
  })
}
getPaths("C:/")
console.log('getPaths() ran')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately it still doesn't work properly. You can see it if you scan a large folder (like `C:/`). It gets all the paths and stores them in memory and only after it found all the paths it starts piping it to `.gz` file. But I was trying to make it writing the found paths to `.gz`file as it finds them one by one so it doesn't store all of them in memory

Comment: I couldn't figure out exactly why this happens. It seems to me that the `walkdir` module is overwhelming  the CPU and causes a delay in the write to the file, but I'm still not sure

Comment: I tried to `fork` the `walkdir` process, it's a little better, but still, it seems that the filesystem is overwhelmed (when I log the walkdir output to the screen it buffers everything, and without log it starts to write the file before reading all the files)

Comment: Well, I tried getting and writing paths using a custom function (with `fs.readdirSync`), it reduces the memory usage because I don't store any paths, I just write them as it finds them, but `zip` still writes the paths into the file only after the function found all of them. I don't know, maybe it's an issue with its being synchronous.  Anyway, thanks for trying, mate